# Using EWS to add a new attachment to a new email during compose

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, msdn

Is it possible to add a new attachment to an email while the email is being composed using EWS?

Based on the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn726694(v=exchg.150).aspx), creating an email and adding an attachment creates a draft of the email instead of adding the attachment to compose email window. Similarly, since the email is being composed it doesn't have an id that I can pass to the "Add an attachment to an existing email" case.

The add-in I'm building must support Outlook 2016 in all of its forms, including the case where it's backed by a standalone Exchange server which is why I'm not using the REST API. Any solutions that involve the XML version of EWS would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the Office JS library is available in Outlook 2016, including when its backed by a standalone Exchange server, and I do not need to use EWS to add an attachment to the compose window. Instead I can use the function `Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync()` to add the attachment and `Office.context.mailbox.item.removeAttachmentAsync()` to remove it.